# How to loop append specific values from text files into a matrix with diagonals pre-specified in R?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, matrix

I would like to write a loop to append specific values grabbed from text files to fill **the upper triangular half** of a matrix in R. So far this is what I have:

```
M <- diag(50)
ct <- 1
for (sub in (filenames$file_id)) {
subj <- read.table(paste0(data_dir, 'subject_', sub, '.txt'), sep="", fill=TRUE)
ht <- as.character(subj$V2[grep("ht",subj$V1)])
### insert code to append ht value from each subject text file into the matrix accordingly ###
ct <- ct + 1
}
```

Would appreciate any helpful insight please, thank you!

Comment: What's the problem? M[row,col] <- newvalue

Comment: That is not specific toward this particular question.

Comment: You need to supply a reprex, a minimum reproducible example. Give us an example of the subj variable using `dput(subj)` so we can understand what your data is and what you're trying to do.